# Display the lines of solar altitude on the map

Tags: the-sun, sunrise, sunset

Following this question:

[Calculate lines of equal solar altitude](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47197/calculate-lines-of-equal-solar-altitude)

I would like to have the possibility of displaying the lines of equal solar altitude on the map as per the image below:

[image]

including also the values below the horizon.

Is there any software or (for example) Pythin library, which could do something like this?

Comment: Does the map need to be that detailed, or would a simpler map suffice?

Comment: I would rather to have the detailed map like OpenStreetMaps or something

Comment: One way would be to compute the [Geographic Position](https://www.celestialprogramming.com/snippets/geographicPosition.html) of a body, then plot a circle of equal altitude around it for each ring you want.